# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin x)}}{x^2}dx=1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin x)}}{x^2}dx$. Prove that $I=1$.

Desmos shows that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{100}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x\sin{x})}{x^2}dx=0.9984\dots$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10000}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x\sin{x})}{x^2}dx=0.999987\dots$.

So I think it's a safe bet that $I=1$.

**Context**

I recently learned [that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(x\sin{x})}}{x^2}dx=\pi/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4705703/398708). On a whim, I squared the numerator, and then to my surprise this new integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin x)}}{x^2}dx$ seems to also have a closed form - in fact $1$, the simplest closed form of all.

**My attempt**

There are [lots of ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13344/398708) to show that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx=\pi/2$. I've been trying to apply these to $I$. For example I tried to use [integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13348/398708), but the fact that $I$ has sine within sine makes things difficult.

Comment: This integral could be a good candidate for contour integration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similar to [Gary's approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706164/16033) to the other integral, we can use the [Jacobi–Anger expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E2) $$\cos(z \sin \theta) = J_{0}(z) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{2k}(z) \cos(2 k \theta) $$ to write the integral as $$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin x)}}{x^2} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(2x \sin x)}{2x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-J_{0}(2x)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{2k}(2x) \cos(2kx)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx. \end{align}$$

For basically the same reason that I explained in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706247/16033) to your other question, the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{2k}(2x) \cos(2kx)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx$$ vanishes for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

Therefore, using the fact that  $J_{0}(x)$ and $J_{0}(x) -1$ have the same Mellin transform but different regions of convergence (which I showed in the addendum to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4470124/16033) using Ramanujan's Master Theorem), we have  $$ \begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin x)}}{x^2} \, \mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1- J_{0}(2x)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-J_{0}(u)}{u^{2}} \, \mathrm du \\ &= \lim_{s \to -1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1-J_{0}(u) \right)u^{s-1} \, \mathrm du \\ &=  -\lim_{s \to -1} \frac{2^{s-1}\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{s}{2} \right)} \\ &= -\frac{2^{-2} \, \Gamma \left(- \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \\ &= -\frac{1}{4} \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\left(- \frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \,  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \\ &= 1. \end{align}$$

Comment: You are typing too fast for the old man. I was also using @Gary's answer when your nice answer came in. So, I added an asymptotic, that's all. By the way, for sure, $(+1)$. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici   Thanks.  I actually don't type that fast.  I just happened to see the question about a minute after it was posted.

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment*

Starting from @Random Variable's nice answer, we can even compute
$$I(a,b)=\int_a^b \frac{\sin^2{(x\sin (x))}}{x^2}\,dx$$ since
$$\int \frac{1-J_0(u)}{u^2}\,du= \frac 1 u \left(\,
   _1F_2\left(-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},1;-\frac{u^2}{4}\right)-1
   \right)$$
$$\int_0^t \frac{1-J_0(u)}{u^2}\,du=\frac 1 t \left(\,
   _1F_2\left(-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},1;-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)-1
   \right)$$ whose asymptotic is
$$\int_0^t \frac{1-J_0(u)}{u^2}\,du=1-\frac 1 t +\frac{\cos (t)-\sin (t)}{\sqrt{\pi }\, t^{5/2}}+\frac{21 (\sin (t)+\cos (t))}{8 \sqrt{\pi } \,t^{7/2}}+\cdots$$